# make this use closure

Tags: javascript, closures

So I know I need closure to solve a problem with conflicting counters in my script, but try as i might I just can't understand how to do it. My script is:

```
var i= 1;

function we_start_slide(gallery, img, delay)
{
    var gallery_images= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(img));
    var img_count= img.length;

    document.getElementById(gallery + '_slide').innerHTML=gallery_images[0];
    test= setInterval(function(){we_slide_show(gallery, gallery_images, img_count)}, delay);
}
function we_slide_show(gallery, gallery_images, img_count)
{
    document.getElementById(gallery + '_slide').innerHTML=gallery_images[i];
    if(i < img_count-1) i++;
    else i=0;
}
```

Could some one please explain to me how use closure to hide the counter variable i so that other fucntions cannot change it? thank you.

Comment: Just move everything inside `we_start_slide`?

Comment: if you do that then i is lost after we_start_slide finishes.

Comment: No, it's not, that's the whole point of closures.

Comment: yes. but just moving it inside doesn't create closure.

Comment: The closure is created when the function expression is evaluated in that scope. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Closure example:

```
(function(window){
  var i = 1;
  window.we_slide_show = function (gallery, gallery_images, img_count)
  {
      document.getElementById(gallery + '_slide').innerHTML=gallery_images[i];
      if(i < img_count-1) i++;
      else i=0;
  };
})(window);
```